# How to force emerge to install a newer version of a package?

Tags: gentoo, emerge

I'm using Gentoo and needing to install a newer version of `gcc`, available in the [official Gentoo package repo](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/sys-devel/gcc).

I want to do the equivalent of `apt-get install gcc=8.0.3-r1` but cannot figure out how. It doesn't even need to be version 8 - any version at or above 4.8 will do.

What I have tried:

`emerge =sys-devel/gcc-8.0.3` returns `there are no ebuilds to satisfy "=sys-devel/gcc-8.0.3".`

`emerge-webrsync` returns `command not found`. `eix-sync` seems to complete successfully, but then `eix sys-devel/gcc` only returns versions up to 4.7. I was hoping one of those would be the equivalent to `apt-get update` but it doesn't appear that way.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you see only `sys-devel/gcc-4.7` and older, your sync failed. At first you need to fix that. This needs some research and is not an FAQ which can be solved with sx. I suggest to ask for help on one of the support channels https://www.gentoo.org/support/

Comment: _emerge-webrsync returns command not found_ - this is a bad sign, as portage might be broken (the executable should be available). Also all GCC versions under 6.X.X are masked in the current tree - this means your installation must be very much outdated. Can you run `emerge --sync`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

As hoefling stated, I too believe your portage is broken, as `emerge-webrsync` is the fallback command.  All versions below gcc:6 are either masked or hard masked and multilib has now changed.

### Solution

1. Fix Portage.  Read [Project:Portage/Fixing broken portage
   < Project:Portage](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Portage/Fixing_broken_portage). Current version is 2.3.66-r1, but **DO NOT** go above 2.2.13 as the note states
2. Mask every version of `sys-kernel/gentoo-sources` >= your kernel version.  As a personal opinion, we need a sane compiler chain to build a stable kernel.
3. Test `emerge --sync`.
4. If step 3 completes, run `emerge -1 portage`. This replaces the portage you built in Step 1, with the official portage from the tree.

### Optional

1. Rebuild the entire system:

   - `emerge -e @system`
   - `emerge -e @world`
2. Unmask your kernel. and update it.

Comment: Thank you. Even though I have abandoned this problem, I'll accept your solution in case anyone else comes across the same problem.